# Create a control

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4

i would like to know that is there any control in iphone is able to the select the range?.

i mean the user need to select the AGE between 10-20 and 20-30 and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't your very hot be at the top and very cold at the bottom?

Comment: @ginamin: hi! is that possible to create control like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [`UIPickerView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPickerView_Class/Reference/UIPickerView.html)

Set each range (e.g. 10-20) as a text item in the picker.